# Block HTTP 1.0 with nginx

Tags: nginx

My server is under a heavy attack. Most requests are coming this way:

```
46.43.84.214 - - [15/May/2012:11:21:45 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 65859 "2r4k68998q24ay.ru" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Vonna.com b o t)"
```

The HTTP protocol version is same for all such requests. Can I block HTTP 1.0 requests on a web server level somehow? I have tried this to eliminate the attack (redirect to an empty file):

```
if ($server_protocol ~* "HTTP/1.0") {
    rewrite ^/ http://example.com/white.txt;
}
```

Does not seem to help much, I don't see any such redirects in the logs. I use nginx 1.0.9 as a reverse proxy with Apache 2.2.3.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "Vonna.com" ) {
    return 444;
}
```

444 will close the connection without returning anything, assuring the lowest possible impact. Though if you want to inform possible legitimate users, use something like 400 perhaps.

Additionally, perhaps block by referrer, though most bots will easily spoof that too.

As far as blocking entire HTTP 1.0 is concerned, you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) first. If you'd still like to implement the block as a temporary solution, something like this should work.

```
if ($server_protocol ~* "HTTP/1.0") {
    return 444;
}
```

Basically the same thing you had, except with no rewrite - if I'm reading it right, your usage made it just stay in a permanent loop.

Comment: But they send all requests with a uniq user agent header. What do I do on this matter? You advice is very promising.

Comment: You can download it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17184781/down/nginx.conf. That you very much.

Comment: Fixed up the answer so it actually makes sense. But still, take blocking HTTP 1.0 as the last resort, any only temporary, since there's a chance you might block normal users, as low as it is. Rather identify recurring/related source IPs/user agents/referrers and block on that.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it will be a permanent block, of course.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with Nginx 1.8.

```
if ($server_protocol = HTTP/1.0) {
    return 444;
}
```

My reason for doing it was different.  The Qualys Threat Report detected CVE-2000-0649, "allows remote attackers to obtain the internal IP address of the server via an HTTP 1.0 request", on my server.  I have the liberty of doing this because our site only supports limited browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right variable: `$server_protocol` instead of `$http_user_agent`.

Comment: Thanks, but it was just a typo. I've corrected my original post.