# Ignoring HTTP 1.0 requests in IIS

Tags: http, iis

Is there a way to ignore HTTP 1.0 requests in IIS (7.0)? I don't see any reason to accept requests that are not HTTP 1.1.

Comment: I see even less reason to *reject* HTTP/1.0. It hasn't been marked "obsolete" yet, it's still in use by simpler (non-browser) HTTP clients, and is probably even handled by the same code as HTTP/1.1 (which was explicitly designed to remain compatible with 1.0). It would be just additional work with absolutely no gain.

Comment: Additionally, see [Is HTTP/1.0 still in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073392/is-http-1-0-still-in-use) from stackoverflow

Comment: @mikemaccana: No, that's a reason to reject clients which don't send the `Host` header. That's _not_ a reason to reject HTTP 1.0 clients, most of which _do_ send `Host`.

Comment: @grawity: You're right, I misread the RFC. It says to reject **clients that identify as HTTP 1.1** but that don't send `Host`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: download and install [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).
Step 2: add the following to your `web.config` file, to the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}" pattern="HTTP/1.0" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This will refuse all HTTP 1.0 requests with a HTTP 504 error code.

Edit: after installing URL Rewrite, you can also configure rewrite rules in IIS Manager:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! I tested using `curl -v -0 http://localhost` and it does indeed respond with an abort.

Comment: I have tried the above re-write rule but it did not give us the desired result. HTTP 1.0 request is still getting processed and internal IP address of the server is disclosed.

Comment: The internal IP address is disclosed lower down in the stack, before it gets to URL Rewrite and Customer Error page.

Comment: URL Rewrite module is very late in the HTTP request processing due to IIS architecture, so if a response is generated (usually by Windows HTTP API/http.sys) before reaching URL Rewrite module this rule won't be able to block the leak. You don't have much control on HTTP API, so the common workaround is to block HTTP 1.0 requests long before they reach Windows/IIS, such as setting up a reverse proxy of nginx in front, https://serverfault.com/questions/389132/block-http-1-0-with-nginx