# How to prevent nginx reveals his private address?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have nginx and a few web servers behind as you can see below:

```
server {
    listen    80  default_server;
    server_name _;
    return      444;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/adefault.log;

}
server {
    listen 443 default;
    server_name     _;
    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/cert-default-ssl.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/private-default-ssl.pem;
    return 403;
}
server {
    listen a.b.c.d:80;
    listen a.b.c.d:443 ssl;
    server_name cloud.example.com;
    if ($host = ldap.example.com) {
                 return 404;
        }
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/cloud.example.com/privkey.pem;


    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' cloud.example.com example.com";
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/cloud.log;
        client_max_body_size 300m;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          https://cloud.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_secret_header;


    }
   location ~ .well-known {
                 root /srv/web;
        }
  }
server {
    listen a.b.c.d:80;
    listen a.b.c.d:443 ssl;
    server_name gw.example.com;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors example.com cloud.example.com";
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/gw.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/gw.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/gw.log;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          https://gw.example.com;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

    }
   location ~ .well-known {
                 root /srv/web;
        }
  }
```

If I run a software such a nikto it tells me that

> RFC-1918 IP address found in the 'location' header. The IP is...

How can I prevent that nginx returns to http client his private ip address?

Answer (score 1):

The `Location` header is used in external redirects. Try setting the following in the relevant `server` container:

```
server_name_in_redirect on
```

To get Nginx to use the defined `server_name` in the `Location` header.

Comment: Sadly, that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/389136/129090 I've made the following workaround:

```
if ($server_protocol ~* "HTTP/1.0") {
return 444;
}
```

Note: With this I prevent to reveal internal ip address of nginx server, however http client does not get status 444.

Comment: Ah, so it's only for HTTP/1.0 requests that you are seeing the IP address returned? An HTTP/1.0 request may not contain a `Host` header, so could well be a direct request to your server's IP address. (?)